# Laying your own telephone cable (from demarcation point)

Tags: cables, telephone, internet

So my telephone cable from the demarcation point to my apartment is broken and there's no way to get a proper technician to fix it in the next few weeks. So I tried to do it myself, but the router keeps blinking, indicating that the connection isn't functional.

I made some pics from my phone to illustrate what I did. In this first picture, there is a little Telecom box which the Telecom technician connected. This is right at the demarcation point. Instead of plugging the telephone cable in there, I cut the wires and connected them to a telephone cable. This can be seen in the background. Its a 2x2 telephone cable, but I only connected the white and red cables. The second picture shows what I did at the other end, in my appartment. cable then goes straight into the router, but without any effect. Does anyone have an idea how to proceed? Would it make sense to get a Multimeter to detect it there are some voltages measurable, or is that doubtful even it it works? Any advice is appreciated. [image]
[image]

Comment: "*So I tried to do it myself*", don't.

Comment: :) we'll, living without an internet connection is not really an option these days, especially if you need it for work. Technicians I reached offered appointments for 2020 .... Is there a particular reason why this is a bad idea?

Comment: does it go thru a high pass filter?  Time to make friends with neighbours and use guest wifi

Comment: I don't understand your photos. Probably because I'm not familiar with your country's telephone cabling devices. What country are you in? Which wires are coming from the phone company? What is the demarcation device? Have you tried connecting your modem directly to the demarcation device? What type of DSL service do you have? What is the model of your modem?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe the trouble is in the underground section? If it is above ground it can simply be spliced.

Comment: You might try reversing the wire connections.  (Are you sure of the orientation of the original connections?)  The best repair would be to open up the customer side of the central junction box and directly connect a pre-wired RJ45 wire assembly to the matching socket, then connect that directly to your modem.  With the existing repair does your phone work correctly? If you have a filter module it should only go on the line branches going to the phone connections.

Comment: How do you know that the feed at the demarcation point is not dead? | Why do you think it's the feed in cable that's broken? | Are you sure that the original wire colours now go, via the extension, to the same indoor terminals as before. | Are you sure your pushed in wires are making good contact? | How? |In correct holes?| Correct polarity? | Clean all 4 wires at demarcation point with sand paper or file then twiwst together well and ideally solder. || There are vast numbers of people who know enough to help at sensible rates and able to arrive this week rather than in 2020.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Bring your router to the demarc point and verify that it works there. You did not mention if you had done this, but if not, you should, as the whole point of a demarc is to say: "If it does not work here the provider needs to fix it. If it does work here the problem is in your wiring." So you need to **test** that.

THEN you can start to concern yourself with the wiring onward from that point. Which appears to bear no resemblance to the North American standards I'm familiar with...